# Vimdiff on mac does not work

Tags: vim

I am trying to get vimdiff working on my mac OX - Darwin 15.6 and vim 7.3. When I run vimdiff with -V option, I see the error below:

```
Calling shell to execute: "diff -a /var/folders/9p/2bnq24nd1qd75xn0sxg172kd6r9fpw/T/vha2EMz/0 /var/folders/9p/2bnq24nd1qd75xn0sxg172kd6r9fpw/T/vha2EMz/1 >/var/folders/9p/2bnq24nd1qd75xn0sxg172kd6r9fpw/T/vha2EMz/2"
Calling shell to execute: "diff /var/folders/9p/2bnq24nd1qd75xn0sxg172kd6r9fpw/T/vha2EMz/0 /var/folders/9p/2bnq24nd1qd75xn0sxg172kd6r9fpw/T/vha2EMz/1 >/var/folders/9p/2bnq24nd1qd75xn0sxg172kd6r9fpw/T/vha2EMz/2"
Error detected while processing function <SNR>6_VimEnter:
line    2:
E810: Cannot read or write temp files
Error detected while processing function <SNR>6_VimEnter:
line    2:
E97: Cannot create diffs
```

vha2EMz folder in /var/folders/9p/2bnq24nd1qd75xn0sxg172kd6r9fpw/T does not exist. I can access /var/folders and create directory in it, so it's not a permission issue. Anyone has any experience with this error on Unix based system?

I checked my /usr/share/vimrc file according to [this](http://skeena.net/kb/vim%20vimdiff%20windows%20e810%20cannot%20read%20or%20write%20temp%20files.txt), but cannot find MyDiff() in there. Is this the issue? Should I replace my /usr/share/vimrc or add MyDiff definition to it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was $SHELL variable was not set. Vim gets the default from $SHELL.